# error in JAX-WS Webservice at time of add nwe method

Tags: web-services

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Method Add is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding wsdl operation with name Add in the wsdl:portType{http://Test/}WSTestService

Comment: could you provide a little bit of background on your issue. Is this exception caught on server or client side?

Comment: I am having the same issue. The exception is happening at the client side and only when you try to call the method from the webservice. I have checked the classes and the annotations for the new added method and everything seems to be correct.  Any ideas?